# onmouseover in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a view where I displayed some titles with checkboxes. When I put the cursor on the title I want to display me some text into a box that contains a little description of the title. I try to put in title the `$row['description']` but it doesn't look ok. I want to configure a box where I have displayed the title the `$row['pubdate']` and `$row['description']`. I've tried `onmouseover` but I don't know how to do the function. Some help?

```
<?php 
  foreach ($query as $row){
    echo  '<tr><td>
      <label class="checkbox">
      .form_checkbox('delete[]', $row['link']).anchor("site/see_art/".$row['feed_id'],$row['title'],'title='.$row['title'].'').
        "</td><td>".substr($row['pub_date'], 5, 12).
      "</label>
    </td></tr>";
  } 
?>
```

Comment: your `label tag` is between 2 `td`. not good

Comment: you could add a hidden div with the title and display it only on hover. really simple with JQuery a little bit more complicated in pure JS.

Comment: i tried to put the desciption in title but it display me only the first word

Answer (score 0):

put a `div` with `position:absolute` in your `label` and show it on mouseover:

HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <INPUT type="checkbox" name="nom"/> Checkbox 1
    <div class="tooltip">title blablabla 1
        <span class="postdate">Date: 2014/03/24</span>
    </div>
</label>
```

JS:

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox");
for(var i=0; i < ele.length; i++){
    ele[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
        var x=event.clientX;
        var y=event.clientY;
        var tooltip = this.querySelector(".tooltip");
        tooltip.style.display="block";
        tooltip.style.top=y+"px";
        tooltip.style.left=x+"px";
    });
    ele[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(el){
        this.querySelector(".tooltip").style.display="none";
    });
}
```

NB: this will not work with IE8, IE8 not have `querySelector`. It could be really easier with JQuery.

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3mpPr/)

Comment: i try your code and does not work. Can you open a chat room and talk about